# How can I change a Windows user's regional settings/date format?

Tags: c#, windows, datetime, registry, regional

I use a VB6/COM+ application which outputs date/time values based on the short date settings in the Control Panel, Regional Settings, for the user that runs it.  The program that then parses that output has a configurable setting for the date format it expects, and presents in the UI.

e.g. If the regional setting for the user is set to mm/dd/yyyy, and it outputs 06/18/2009, the application expecting "18/06/2009" fails with "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

As we usually run this application as a service account, which we have not logged in as interactively to create a profile, we generally set the correct date format and then tick the "Apply all settings to the current user account and the default user profile" option.

I would like to be make the C# configuration utility I have written for this mess to be able to set the date format programmatically for a given user.

**Edit**
I would like nothing more than to change the code, but do not have the ability to do so at this time.

I also know that what I am asking is a bad thing to do.  With regards to "it should be the user's choice" - I **am** that user, as I create it explicitly for the task; I just want to set the date format by a scripted method, rather than having to do the clicking myself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is specifically discouraged by Microsoft. Any solution you may come up with will be a filthy hack that will probably stop working soon.

Think of it this way: who are you to decide those settings? Don't you think that's the user's decision?

Back on topic: find an unambiguous format for the applications to communicate in, such as `YYYYMMDD`. The application that displays can then simply respect the actual user settings, as it should.

But, since you can't change it, just poke into the registry:

Current user:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International
```

Specific user:

```
HKEY_USERS\(user SID)\Control Panel\International
```

Default user:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International
```

`sShortDate` is probably the value you want to change.

Comment: I know that it's a bad thing to do.  I am that user, I create it explicitly for the task; I just want to set the date format by a scripted method, rather than having to do the clicking myself.

I would like nothing more than to change the code, but do not have the ability to do so.

Comment: Thanks - I'm pretty confident your answer will work, but either way your pragmatic attitude to the problem definitely deserves the rep.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to modify the profile to suit your needs, why not just ignore the profile settings and hardcode the format you want in your app?

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
Imports System.Threading
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-US", False)
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", "sShortDate", "M/d/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

While persistently changing a user's culture (regional settings) is to be done cautiously, there are legitimate use cases.

On Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 and above, Windows PowerShell comes with the
[`Set-Culture` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852137.aspx), which is the programmatic equivalent of choosing a different region  via Control Panel (`intl.cpl`).

For instance, `Set-Culture fr-CA` is the equivalent of interactively choosing region `French (Canada)` for the current user.

<sup>Caveat: *Mixed* cultures such as `en-DE` (sic) appear not to work as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866252/45375) of mine.</sup>

While it won't be fast, it is possible to call PowerShell commands from C#.