# Syntax error when parsing String to Date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to parse a String in VB to Date in an Excel macro like this:

```
Sub report_macro()

    Dim nRow As Long
    Dim sDueDate As String
    Dim dueDate As Date

    For nRow = 5 To 65536
        If Not Range("A" & nRow).Value = "" Then
            sDueDate = Range("G" & nRow).Value
            dueDate = Date.ParseExact(sDueDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
            If Range("H" & nRow).Value = 57600 Then

                Range("A" & nRow & ":I" & nRow).Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = 13551615
                End With
            End If
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next nRow

End Sub
```

I'm getting Sytnax error at the line:

```
dueDate = Date.ParseExact(sDueDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`Date.ParseExact` is a VB.NET method. You are running a macro in Excel which uses VBA not VB.NET ([Differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Visual_Basic_and_Visual_Basic_.NET))

Your best option is probably just to assign the value directly to the date variable (the `Value` property is actually a Variant):

```
dueDate = Range("G" & nRow).Value
```

Alternatively you can do a simple conversion using [`CDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx)

If you really want to parse it have a look at this answer: [A better CDate for VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059930/a-better-cdate-for-vb6)

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there anything more simple to just assign a date from a cell formatted as a date to a Date variable? It seems as something common to do, so I thought it would be trivial.

Comment: To assign a Date to a variable from some cell, why not just: Dim DT as Date: If IsDate(myCell) then DT = myCell