# Changing system language from control panel using c#

Tags: c#, controlpanel

I'm trying to test an application to see if it displays the right language strings when I change the system language. I intend on automating the process. So I'll change the language, launch my AUT and check to see if the correct language strings are being displayed. Is there an API that allows me to access the control panel and change the system language to say French from English. And then later German and so on. I need this to happen in the background. I could run a batch file to launch control panel using :

```
control /name Microsoft.RegionalAndLanguageOptions
```

This launches control panel, but how do I change the language. Ideally I don't even want control panel to be displayed.

Comment: Google sent me here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: i think registry is the best option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530350/changing-the-region-and-language-os-setting-programmatically