# Change System's Date and Decimal Format

Tags: vb.net-2010

Im using date format as "18.08.2016" and decimal format as "1.526,42" in my program. But some computers date and decimal format is different. For example their formats are like "18/08/2016" and "1,526.42".
So i want to change the date and decimal format of the users computer when my program starts to run. Is it possible to change in visual basic 2010 codes?

Comment: This would be somewhat brute force and conflict with the users preferences. Rather you should solve the issue caused by different (localized) formatting. Could you give a small example form your code where this is a problem? Usually this happens when you are handling strings where you should handle DateTime objects or Decimal values.

Comment: You are right. Some of my program's user also uses an account program. That program changes the format when user open it. So after running that program, my program starts to give some error. For example, user has made some records with my program which stored to database like "18.08.2016". Then user opened that account program and the systems date time format changed to dd/mm/yyyy format. And when user wants to reach the record program gives an error like "unknown date time format"

Comment: [How can I change a Windows user's regional settings/date format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014120/205233) has hints where to look in the registry.