# Issue with English non-US Culture

Tags: powershell, windows-10, locale, culture, currentculture

I am able to use `Set-Culture` (Powershell as Admin) to set the Current Culture to `"en-DE"` which is English (Germany). However, when I run the different PS commands to view the Current Culture, I am still getting `en-US`. I checked my Region (Format) and Location as well.

Do I have to change the system locale as well to Germany (German) ?

This is causing an error in an application, because the datetime format is different from en-DE to en-US and causing the date to be read incorrectly.

When I `Set-Culture` to `de-DE`, everything appears to be in working order.

I make sure to run Powershell Console as Administrator, `Set-Culture`, close console. Open Powershell and run `Get-Culture`, `[CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture`, `[CultureInfo]::CurrentUICulture` and a few more to check and and still getting `en-US`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: **Use of `en-DE`** as a culture identifier - i.e., mixing *language* `en` (English) with normally unrelated *region/country* `DE` (Germany) - requires **Windows 10 with release channel `1607` or later** or  **Windows Server 2016**, [according to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx).

However, there's a **bug** that **prevents use of such mixed cultures**, observed on Windows 10 Pro (64-bit; Version 1709, OS Build: 16299.371)

**While you can successfully *set* such mixed-culture values with `Set-Culture`, subsequent sessions do not recognize it and fall back to `en-US`** (as reflected in `$PSCulture`, `Get-Culture` and `[cultureinfo]::currentCulture`)

- This [problem has been reported on UserVoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/33983191-powershell-sessions-don-t-support-mixed-culture-va).
- Note that PowerShell *Core* is not affected (but it doesn't support `Set-Culture`).

---

The rest of this answer discusses persistently setting the current user's culture in general, irrespective of the bug.

---

**`Set-Culture`** - via the registry - **sets the culture for *future* PowerShell sessions (only)**, not (also) for the *current* session.

**`Get-Culture`**, by contrast, only ever **reports the *current* session's culture *at session-startup time***. That is, if you change the culture *during* a session (see below), it will *not* be reflected in `Get-Culture`.

In order **to also apply the newly set culture to the *current* session**, run the following *in addition to* the `Set-Culture` call:

```
[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'
```

**Caveat re *interactive* (command-line) use:**

- In *Windows PowerShell* (still as of v5.1), the active culture is *reset* after every command submitted; e.g.,
  `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'; Get-Date` works as expected, because it is part of the same command line, but when executing just `Get-Date` as the *next* command, the current culture has reverted to the one that was current at *session-startup time*.

  - This problem has been fixed in PowerShell *Core*.

---

This **perhaps surprising asymmetry** - `Set-Culture` only applying to *future* sessions, but `Get-Culture` reporting the *current* session's (startup) culture - is something that [may change in future PowerShell *Core* versions](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3833).